# rails_admin: undefined method `year' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-admin

Using rails_admin, I whenever I try to save an object that has a date field, I get the error message: `undefined method 'year' for nil:NilClass`. Not sure what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it's a bug that's introduced with Ruby 2.2.*

Not sure if it's on the rails_admin team's radar yet, but you can fix it by downgrading to 2.1.*

Comment: Has this been fixed yet, or for later versions of Ruby? Trying to decide whether to up or downgrade